# Meteor Validation Rules and Messages Guidences?

Tags: meteor

I need to know about the usage of **Meteor Rules and Messages** as mentioned in below code.I understand the functionality of below function but i didn't get any idea about the execution and usage of the below function.Can you please check the below code once and suggest me the execution procedure and when validate method will executes and how to display the below messages text.How to cal the below method.I did cal the below method like

```
 setUpValidators();
```

I get errors to cal the method.The error is

[23:12:01.389] `$("#addnewuserdetails").validate is not a function @ http://localhost:3000/app.js?92269b7057a5ba1050e9caeddd680fbe336aeb57:76`

```
    var setUpValidators = function() {
        // set up validations

       console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> setUpValidators");
        var validator = $('#addnewuserdetails').validate({   //addnewuserdetails is form id name
            rules: {
                "userid": {  //userid is textfiled id name
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    maxlength: 50
                },
                "phno": {
                    maxlength: 10
                }
            },
            messages:
               {
                "userid": 
                 {
                    required: "Please enter a userid",
                    minlength: "The title must be at least 5 characters long",
                    maxlength: "The title must be no more than 50 characters long"
                   },
                "phno": 
                  {
                    maxlength: "The title must be no more than 250 characters long"
                   }
            }

        });
    };
```

Comment: Try removing the `var validator = ` part of your code.

Comment: Also got same above error message.I didn't get any idea about this error.So can you please suggest me what to do?.@Firo